# Specify multiple classes for ignoreClass property in MathJax configuration

Tags: mathjax

I have the following code for MathJax configuration. I would like MathJax to ignore elements that have the class `im` or the classes `class1  class2`.

**Question**: 
Is it possible to specify a list of classes for `ignoreClass` property, and if yes then how would it be specified?

I have tried a comma-delimited list of classes for this property, but it did not work, i.e. I tried `class1 class2 , im`,

```
window.MathJax = {
 tex2jax: {
    inlineMath: [['\\$', '\\$'], ["\\(", "\\)"]],
    displayMath: [['$$', '$$'], ["\\[", "\\]"]],
    processEscapes: true,
    ignoreClass: "class1 class2"
   }
};
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation? http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/tex2jax.html

Comment: Got it. I have to use the pipe character as delimiter for multiple ignore classes.Thanks.